# stats_get_csv (Wordpress Stats) to only display top posts (not pages)

Tags: php, code, plugin-jetpack, statistics

I'm trying to get the first 10 posts based on page views through Wordpress Stats (now called Jetpack).
I managed to get this code to work (approximately..) after digging for hours over the forums (because variables and code changed from time to time):

```
        <?php
        if ( function_exists('stats_get_csv') && $top_posts = stats_get_csv( 'postviews', "days=10&limit=10")) {
        echo '<ol class="most-viewed">';
          foreach ( $top_posts as $post ) {
            if($post['post_id'] && get_post($post['post_id']))
              echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $post['post_id'] ) . '">' . 
                  get_the_title( $post['post_id'] ) . '</a> (' . number_format_i18n( $post['views']) .' visits)</li>';
          }
          echo '</ol>';
        }
        ?>
```

Now I'd like to exclude pages from this list and only have posts. The problem is that the WordPress.com Stats API does not offer a post_type filter. I should put somewhere this

```
if ( !isset($post->post_type) || $post->post_type != 'post' )
```

can you help me pointing out where should I add it?

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the post type with the post ID:

```
if ( 
    $post['post_id'] 
    && get_post( $post['post_id'] ) 
    && 'post' === get_post_type( $post['post_id'] )
)
```

Comment: Yup!! Works! :D

Comment: The strange thing is that if I set days=2&limit=10 I get 6 posts (instead of 10), if I set days=60&limit=10 I get 2 posts, if I set days=-1&limit=10 I get just 1 post!!! Why does this happen? :(
The blog has about 2000 articles so there are of course more than 10 posts. :D

Comment: I don’t know. Sounds like a separate question.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Will open a new one. :)

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71539/stats-get-csv-retrieve-just-a-few-posts-not-the-one-i-set-in-limit-parameter